# Derivative of determinant of symmetric matrix wrt a scalar

Tags: matrices, derivatives, determinant, trace, matrix-calculus

For a given square symmetric invertible matrix $\mathbf{X}$ and scalar $\alpha$ (such that the entries of $\mathbf{X}$ depend on $\alpha$), I would like to use the following well-known expression for the derivative of the determinant wrt a scalar (e.g. see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Derivative)):

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \det(\mathbf{X}) = \det(\mathbf{X}) \operatorname{tr} \left( \mathbf{X}^{-1} \frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \alpha} \right) $$

However, I am concerned that this expression may not apply when there exists any kind of special "structure" in the matrix (e.g. an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix contains fewer than $n^2$ independent entries).

Consider for a moment another situation, where such structure matters: differentiating the determinant wrt the matrix entries (instead of a scalar). First, let $\mathbf{Y}$ be a square invertible "unstructured" matrix (i.e. all elements are independent). It is well-known (e.g. see [The Matrix Cookbook](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf) section 2.1.2, or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Derivative)) that, in this case:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{Y}} \det(\mathbf{Y}) = \det(\mathbf{Y}) \, (\mathbf{Y}^{-1})^T $$

Now consider $\mathbf{X}$ again, a square *symmetric* matrix. In this case, the entries are no longer independent (as described in [The Matrix Cookbook](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf), beginning of section 2.8), so we have instead (see section 2.8.2 for the symmetric case):

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{X}} \det(\mathbf{X}) = \det(\mathbf{X}) \, (2 \mathbf{X}^{-1} - (\mathbf{X}^{-1} \circ \mathbf{I})) $$

So, when differentiating the determinant wrt matrix entries, the matrix structure clearly matters.

Here is my question: when differentiating a matrix determinant wrt a scalar, does the matrix structure matter? And if so, what is the correct expression for $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \det(\mathbf{X})$ for the specific case where $\mathbf{X}$ is symmetric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at what happens when derivative of the determinant of an invertible matrix $A$ with respect to itself. Apparently, the result is a matrix, say $D$, then we have
$$D^q_p=\left(\frac{\partial\det A}{\partial A}\right)^q_p=\frac{\partial(\epsilon_{i_1\ldots i_n}a^{i_1}_1\cdots  a^{i_n}_n)}{\partial a^p_q}$$
where $\epsilon$ is Levi-Civita symbol and Einstein notation is used. If $A$ has no special structure that each of $n^2$ components are seen as independent, we can proceed to
$$D^q_p=\epsilon_{i_1\ldots i_n}a_1^{i_1}\cdots\frac{\partial a^{i_p}_q}{\partial a^p_q}\cdots a_n^{i_n}$$
However when $A=A^T$ is symmetric, each product has 2 terms that depend on $a^p_q$, hence
$$D^q_p=\epsilon_{i_1\ldots i_n}\left(a_1^{i_1}\cdots\frac{\partial a^{i_p}_p}{\partial a^p_q}\cdots a^{i_q}_q\cdots a_n^{i_n}+a_1^{i_1}\cdots a^{i_p}_p\cdots\frac{\partial a^{i_q}_q}{\partial a^p_q}\cdots a_n^{i_n}\right)$$
This leads to different forms of derivative. Yet it is now clear that the derivative of an invertible matrix w.r.t a scalar doesn't depend on its structure.