# Formula for $k$th order derivative of the determinant of a matrix?

Tags: derivatives, determinant, matrix-calculus

## Background

[Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) tells us that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\det A(t) = \operatorname{tr} \left( \operatorname{adj}(A(t)) \frac{dA(t)}{dt} \right) = (\det A(t)) \cdot \operatorname{tr} \left( A(t)^{-1} \cdot \frac{dA(t)}{dt} \right)$$

for the first derivative of a matrix $A(t)$ with respect to parameter $t$. A [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325807/second-derivative-of-a-determinant) showed that there exists such a formula

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \alpha^2}\det A= \det(A) \left[\text{tr}^2\left( A^{-1} A_{\alpha} \right) +
         \text{tr} \left( A^{-1} A_{\alpha^2} \right)+N\right]$$

for the second partial derivatives.

## Question

> Is there such a formula for the $k$th order derivative
>
> $$\frac{d^k}{dt^k}\det A(t) = ?$$
>
> of the determinant of such a matrix?

---

Note that the question [*nth derivative of determinant wrt matrix*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890552/nth-derivative-of-determinant-wrt-matrix?rq=1) is only a special case since here I am assuming each entry is function of a parameter $t$ that I am taking the derivative with respect to.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @dtn Not yet. In the mean time it suffices for me to use a computer algebra system for a given derivative order and matrix size. But an answer here would be appreciated!